# Dudas con vh y vw

Tags: css, web

Hola y gracias de antemano por todas las respuestas que me puedan dejar ^^. Mi problema o duda esta en que trato de que mis imagenes agrupadas por `flex-wrap` hagan scroll unicamente hacia abajo sin embargo no entiendo porque se hace un pequeño scroll al costado no se supone que `100vw` es todo el ancho del documento o pantalla.

Por otro lado note que si mis imagenes no hacen scroll hacia abajo tampoco se hace scroll al costado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El CSS que uso es:

```
*{ 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  user-select: none; 
  color: white; 
} 
body{ 
    background-color: black; 
} 
.cabecera{ 
         width: 100vw; 
         max-width: 100vw; 
         height: 50vh; 
         background-color: orange; 
} 
.contenido{ 
        width: 100vw; 
        max-width: 100vw; 
        max-height: 100%; 
        display: flex; 
        flex-wrap: wrap; 
} 
.contenido img{
        width: 25vw; 
        height: 20vh; 
}
```

El documento HTML que uso es:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="cabecera"></header>

    <main class="contenido">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="">
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, te sugiero que no pongas tu codigo como una imagen sino que lo pegues para que podamos utilizarlo.

Comment: Debes colocar el código en la pregunta, no en imágenes, así es mas dificl ayudarte, ya que el código debe probarse antes de ayudarte a encontrar una solución.

Comment: Claro franco lo siento soy nuevo, uhmmm como estoy trabajando con imagenes locales pues dejo el codigo de mi css

Comment: puedes poner el codigo

Comment: *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    user-select: none;
    color: white;
}
body{
    background-color: black;
}
.cabecera{
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: orange;
}
.contenido{
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.contenido img{
    width: 25vw;
    height: 20vh;
}

Comment: el codigo debe de ir arriba

Comment: Escribe el código y coloca cualquier imagen sacada de Internet, por otro lado puedes inspeccionar tu página y descubrir que elemento está causando ese desbordamiento

Comment: ahora el html te falta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia el 100vw de tus contenedores a:

```
.cabecera, contenido {width: 100%;}
```

y quita el max-width, y cambia el ancho de tus imágenes a:

```
.contenido img {width: 25%; height: auto;}
```

No en todos los casos se debe usar vw y vh.

Comment: punto a favor es correcto lo comprobe

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar en tus width '%' en lugar de 'vw' y eliminar los max-width que has utilizado.

```css
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; user-select: none; color: white; } body{ background-color: black; } .cabecera{ width: 100%; height: 50vh; background-color: orange; } .contenido{ width: 100%; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; } .contenido img{ width: 25%; height: auto; }
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="cabecera"></header>

    <main class="contenido">
        <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">
        <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">            <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">            <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">            <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">            <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">            <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">            <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">            <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">            <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">            <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">            <img src="https://bangho.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/159284-360-360/pc-completa-optima-b08-a6-amd-4gb?v=637267958411870000" alt="">
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Por qué este fragmento de código resuelve la pregunta? Procura siempre hacer una breve descripción, cómo lo deben usar, etc.

Comment: Acabo de ver que @Elboy lo ha resuelto de igual manera y explicado correctamente. Voy a dejar su respuesta como la correcta.